# ¿Cómo convierto una imagen en SQL en bytes en C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

tengo esta tabla en SQL server que tiene una variable en formato image.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al momento de pasarla a Visual Studio como Byte[], me dicen que no puedo convertirla. ¿Qué tengo que añadir para que me lo valide?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor lee esto https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es bien sencillo:

```
p.ImagPromo = (byte[]) dr["ImagPromo"];
```

Si puede tener valores nulos entonces es mejor lo siguiente:

```
   var ordinal = dr.GetOrdinal("ImagPromo");
   p.ImagPromo = dr.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? (byte[]) null : (byte[]) dr.GeValue(ordinal);
```

Dicho esto, el tipo `image` está obsoleto en SQL Server desde hace décadas deberías usar `varbinary(max)` en su lugar.

Comment: Haz otra pregunta. En StackOverflow se hace pregunta a pregunta

Answer (score 0):

toByte lo convierte a Byte pero tu propiedad es Byte[].

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
p.ImagPromo = (byte[])dr["ImagPromo"]
```

Y si lo quieres convertir en imagen

```
Image i;
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(p.ImagPromo)) {
                using (Image imageFromStream = Image.FromStream(memoryStream)) {
                    i = (Image)new Bitmap(imageFromStream);
                }
 }
```